# Setup Logstash Netflow Dashboads and Visualizations

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Is there some way to setup Kibana Netflow Dashboards and Visualizations from Logstash(Module NETFLOW) application?

`VERSION: Elasticsearch-7-0-1` and `Kibana-7-0-1` and `Logstash-7-3-1`

Obs1 : I can't use CLI option (`bin/logstash --modules netflow --setup -M netflow.var.input.udp.port=NNNN`).

I tried putting these lines in the `logstash.yml` file:

```
modules:
  - name: netflow
    var.input.udp.port: 9995
    var.elasticsearch.hosts: "ELASTICSEARCH-IP:9200"
    var.kibana.host: "KIBANA-IP:5601"
```

I tried putting `--setup`, in the `startup.options` file:

```
# Arguments to pass to logstash
LS_OPTS="--path.settings ${LS_SETTINGS_DIR} --setup"
```

The Dashboards and Visualizations still aren't loading.

Comment: May I ask you why you can not use the CLI tool?

Comment: Cause my structure don't permit it.